# I got error when press F12 Go to definition in Visual Studio 2015 / C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

When I press F12 (Go To Definition) in Visual Studio 2015 I get this error message:

> One or more errors occured

I already tried:

1. Closing the solution
2. Deleting the .suo file
3. Re-building the solution

.. but that didn't fix it.

Please help.

Comment: Does it say anything about those errors?

Comment: How to do it: Did you try turning it off and on again? If you mean to close VS and start again - yea.
About: Does it say anything about those errors? Not only the window with this label

Comment: Just in case, try Tools | Import and Export Settings => Reset all settings (after saving your current settings first).

Comment: I also get this problem.  Have also tried disabling extensions and running Visual Studio in Safe Mode, with no resolution so far.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[VS 2015 Update 1](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2015-update1-vs.aspx) should fix this problem.

<strike>I have made an extension which simply enables/disables "Keep tabs" on each call of "GoToDefinition" command, and seems to work: [GoToDefinition Fix](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7c807aa8-40a4-4c75-9c46-e0ba8b34a367)</strike>

Comment: Unfortunately, this method doesn't work for "Peek Definition", because this command works asynchronously. When you click Alt+F12 it just opens a new window, setting "Keep tabs" is used after a certain delay. Of course, I can simply add `Thread.Sleep()`, but in some cases even 5 seconds is not enough. So, I haven't found a simple solution yet.

Comment: Note to Microsoft: As great as this extension is, sometimes tabs don't get turned back on again. While [Productivity Power Tools 2015](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/34ebc6a2-2777-421d-8914-e29c1dfa7f5d) helps catch the tab mismatch early, there's no substitute for actually pushing the fix out the door.

Comment: Microsoft clams that they fixed it with [VS 2015 CTP 1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2015/10/08/visual-studio-2015-update-1-ctp.aspx)

Comment: @JurijsKovzels >> It does not seem to be the case, I've just installed VS 2015 CTP 1 and the problem is still here: I cannot use Ctrl + F12. Actually it is not about the keyboard shortcut, but about "Go to Declaration" - any keys combination assigned to it does not work...

Comment: @JurijsKovzels Update 1 CTP did fix it for me

Comment: This issue has raised from the dead with Visual Studio 2017. It affects version 15.2.

Answer (score 29):

This is an issue with C# and tabs instead of spaces when attempting to hit the metadata of an external assembly.  It may be related the inferred position of the insertion point.

[image]

### Others have documented this

There are a couple of Connect tickets [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1577587) and [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1579025/f12-go-to-definition-to-framework-type-method-doesnt-work-when-keep-tabs-instead-of-insert-spaces-is-used) and a [Github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/4019) on this.  There is also a discussion [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/de-DE/3a331ad9-4217-480b-a299-62587d22b1db/visual-studio-2015-go-to-definition-is-not-working-on-referenced-assemblies?forum=visualstudiogeneral).

### Visual Studio 2015 Update 1

This issue is addressed in [Update 1](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2015-update1-vs.aspx) so please install!

### Poor workaround for RTM

The options dialog remembers the last page and remains there on subsequent opens.  I have a keyboard shortcut to open the options pane quickly (Alt + o). I am temporarily changing to spaces, going to definition and then reverting to tabs before making any code changes. This workflow isn't pretty but neither were the 3.0 Nuget issues in VS2015 either (Nuget 3 has improved to date).

Comment: Very frustrating + I don't see what tabs have to do with 'go to definition'. Thanks for your links anyway.

Comment: @vc74 Go to Definition generates C# code when you use it on external DLLs. The C# code generator is running afoul of the tab setting somehow.

Comment: What an embarrassing bug. How such a basic function combined with an incredibly common configuration setting can miss QA is absolutely beyond me.

Comment: Update 1 didn't fix it. Also it's not enough to just set that option for C#, but you need to set it for all languages involved (in my case XAML (-> WPF) as well). Then you need to actually apply that. Either use something like Notepad++ and replace everything in all files accordingly or you can use Visual Studio Power Tools. If you have installed it and add a new line to a file that is formatted differently (now space instead of tabs as all other lines), Power Tools will bring up a bar asking you if you want to Tabify or Untabify (use spaces) the file.

Answer (score 4):

I found that; if you set **Keep Tab** under **Option** -> **Text Editor** -> ***All Languages*** -> **Tabs**, and it's the same under ***C#***, the **F12** and **Alt + F12** Works just fine.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't fix it over here :-(

Answer (score 2):

[Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 CTP](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2015/10/08/visual-studio-2015-update-1-ctp.aspx) fixes the [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/4019).

Answer (score 1):

This hack is no longer useful now that the Visual Studio bug is fixed. I'm leaving it here in case it's useful a sample for hacking around similar issues that come up.

---

**AutoHotKey to the rescue!** Fighting tirelessly against the evils of bad keyboard UX.

Here's how to set up a script that binds <kbd>Ctrl+F12</kbd> to a key sequence that sets space indents, goes to the definition, and then restores tab indents. Use it instead of F12 to go to definitions outside your codebase:

1. Install [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/).
2. Create a new file somewhere named something like `FixF12.ahk`. Paste into it the script below.
3. Open your Startup folder. You can get there by typing `shell:startup` into the Windows Explorer location bar.
4. Right-click drag `FixF12.ahk` into `Startup` and create a shortcut.
5. Run the shortcut.

Script for `FixF12.ahk`:

```
#NoEnv
SendMode Input

^F12::
WinGetActiveTitle Title
IfInString Title, Microsoft Visual Studio
{
  Send, ^QC{#} tabs{Enter}
  Sleep, 300
  Send, !p
  Sleep, 300
  Send, {Enter}
  Send, {F12}
  Send, !tO
  Sleep, 300
  Send, !k
  Sleep, 300
  Send, {Enter}
}
else
{
  Send, {^F12}
}
```

The script is a hack, complete with flashing dialog boxes and a race condition, but it does the job. Don't forget to upvote the [bug report in Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Feedback/Details/1579025). Hopefully Microsoft will release a fix before Update 1.

Answer (score 0):

The [*Visual Studio 2015 Update 1*](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2015-update1-vs.aspx) solved this problem!