# F12 -- Goto Definition does not work with Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, go-to-definition

Has anyone run into this before? In my freshly installed copy of Visual Studio 2015 Professional I simply cannot get 'F12 - Goto Definition' to work. Nothing happens when I try it. What is more, if I try 'ALT-F12 -- Peek at definition', I just get a blank window saying "A definition for the symbol '(null)' could not be located'. Intellisense is working fine. I do not have a lot of third party tools installed (except some git related ones). I am at my wit's end here.

Can anyone help? I have already re-installed this twice.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I got error when press F12 Go to definition in Visual Studio 2015 / C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31650362/i-got-error-when-press-f12-go-to-definition-in-visual-studio-2015-c-sharp)

Comment: It seems to be a duplicated question. Take a look in this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34140726/890890).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Packages not loading after installing visual studio 2015 RTM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31547947/packages-not-loading-after-installing-visual-studio-2015-rtm)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [vs 2015 cannot go to metadata definition and it shows one or more errors occurred](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31873511/vs-2015-cannot-go-to-metadata-definition-and-it-shows-one-or-more-errors-occurre)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/48322563/5935112

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem with Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition. Deleting the .vs folder fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

This problem was resolved in the visual studio 2015 Update 1. Visual Studio 2015's keep tabs option was breaking F12. This is why the other answers response of deleting your settings file fixed it. The default setting is to keep spaces.

Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/31909360

and

To get the update: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/vs2015-update1-vs

Answer (score 0):

In my case the .vcxproj was incomplete due to a version error