# Peek definition (Alt+F12) no longer does anything in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

While `Goto Definition` works as expected with key <kbd>F12</kbd>,
the hotkey <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> for `Peek Definition` no longer does anything.
How do I restore <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> functionality?

Comment: Does Right Click -> Peek Definition work?

Comment: @AnT It does indeed. The feature was still available, just not the hotkey.

Comment: Downvoter, why the downvote? How can the post be improved?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

One cause of this is Nvidia GeForce Experience intercepting Alt presses while listening for Alt+Z, which is the activation toggle for Nvidia ShadowPlay.

Fix this by opening GeForce Experience and going to Settings -> General -> In-Game Overlay -> Disabled.

(Thanks to [@Levi Fuller](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2535344/levi-fuller) for the updated solution)

Comment: Thank you for this fix!  May I ask how you discovered this was the issue?  Is there a utility to display which process captures input?

Comment: @LazzMaTazz I spent thirty minutes or so poking around in futility before remembering my recent installation or activation of GeForce Experience's ShadowPlay feature. I then disabled the keybinding and the issue was immediately resolved.

Unfortunately, I'm not aware of any such utility that could have led me to the solution faster.

Comment: Settings -> General -> In-Game Overlay -> Disabled. Settings changed a bit in latest GeForce Experience. Confirmed still fixes issue.

Comment: It's ridiculous that they no longer use Alt+F12 by default now, but still hook this shortcut, even if you'd remove it from the list of keyboard shortcuts with the overlay enabled. So, disabling it is the only way to free this key to me.

Comment: I would kiss your face if you were in front of me! I literally just looked through GeForce Experience's hotkeys and dismissed it as a possible culprit. I have been dealing with this issue on this one PC for a couple of years now... Thank you!

Comment: Fixed on GeForce Experience 3.26.0.131 (Tue Sep 27,2022)

Answer (score 6):

Had similar issue and the fix was simply resetting the hotkey <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> to peek in Visual Studio with following steps:

1. Go to `Tools->Options->Environment->Keyboard`
2. Select (or search) the key `Edit.PeekDefinition` and click on `Remove`
3. Inside the textbox near `Assign` button press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>
4. Finish by pressing `Assign` and `OK` buttons

Here is an image for steps just in case you need:

[image]

PS. This solution also worked when Intel Graphics was opening on <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>

Comment: I am having the same issue.  I tried all of the recommendations above and additionally deleted the hidden .suo files. I have not been able to resurrect this useful feature.

Answer (score 5):

In GeForce Experience, remove the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> keyboard mapping for `Toggle FPS Counter on/off` found in:

`Settings -> General -> In-Game Overlay -> Settings -> Keyboard Shortcuts`

This fixes this issue without disabling the whole `In-Game Overlay` feature.

Comment: Unfortunately, I see the hotkey intercepted even after clearing _all_ hotkeys in GeForce Experience...

Comment: Fixed on GeForce Experience 3.26.0.131 (Tue Sep 27,2022)

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is interested, for me, it was caused by **Razer mouse** applications, specifically "[Razer Cortex](https://www.razer.com/cortex)." Closing it fixed my VS <kbd>ALT+F12</kbd> issues.

As far as I understand, that application enters some gaming mode for a mouse, which turns off the keyboard handle for <kbd>ALT+F12</kbd>, but I'm not sure why.